# Implementation of const iterator compile error

Tags: c++, iterator, constants

I have a hard time wrapping my head around why the following code doesn't work:

```
vector<int> v {12,13,3,12,4,3,7};
auto it = remove(v.cbegin(), v.end(), 3);
```

When I remove the const from `v.cbegin()` it compiles
But the thing is in this case the const iterator is pointing at the first element/index in the vector which is 12. When we are performing `remove` of the integer 3, the first element isn't getting changed at all so why isn't this working? In order for something to be const, we have promised for it not being changed, right? Unless we use const_cast of course.

I appreciate if anyone could explain how the iterator works in this example and when I should be using const iterator because obviously it doesn't work here.

Comment: The `c` in `cbegin` stands for **constant**.

Answer (score 4):

`remove` only has one parameter for the type of iterator involved, so the begin and end iterator have to both be the same type, or it won't compile. So regardless of much else, you can't mix passing `cbegin()` as the start of the range and `end()` as the end of the range.

In this case, you want both of them to be non-const iterators. It's probably better to think of the iterators as defining a range, not just as individual iterators. If you want the algorithm to be able to modify any part of the range, you need to use non-const iterators to create the range. `const_iterator`s are for cases where you only want to be able to look at data in the range, but not modify any of it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Also can I ask two questions. Does an iterator change when the index it's pointing at changes? For instance if it points at index 2 and then we add another number in the beginning of the vector, so the iterator will have index 3, does that mean it's now changed? Or does it change when the NUMBER it is pointing at changes. For instance at index 2 it points at number 13 but if we change it to 24 does that mean that the iterator been changed?

Comment: Also in the same example in the original question, if I now want to remove all the 3's I will just do     

v.erase(it, v.cend());

But in this case it is acceptable to have const iterator even tho we are modifying it

Appreciate an answer :)!

Comment: @KevinR -- a pair of iterators designates a range. Sometimes that range is data in some sort of container, but it doesn't have to be. So don't think of iterators and indexes in the same breath; they're two different things, and, while some containers provide indexing. that has nothing to do with iterators.

Comment: @KevinR There are certain operations that invalidate an `iterator`, like removing an element for example. So, if you have an `iterator` pointing to some element in your container, and then you remove an element from that same container, the `iterator` you already have has now become invalidated and should not be used again.